# Finding and reading text files

Tags: vba, excel

sorry to disturb but I'm very new with VBA and not that good at it.

I would like to know if there is a VBA function that allows to open (and read) all the files of a folder (without opening them in Excel) (it's .txt files) ? 
And if so which one is it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers, I would be very grateful for an answer or some help.

Cheers :)

Comment: you say you want to "Open" the files but then say you do not want to open them...

Comment: sorry, my question was a bit confusing.
I have some files in a folder, I want to read them and work on them but without opening them..

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basics:

```
Dim sLine as String
Open "C:\myFile.txt" For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
  Line Input #1, sLine
  ' do some stuff with sLine
Loop
Close #1
```